# Range Index List from End

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a mock [*'Deal or No Deal'*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deal_or_No_Deal) text-based Python program just for fun to try and learn by projects.
There are cases numbered 1,2,...,25,26.
I'm currently making a function that will display the cases remaining to choose from. This is what I have so far:

```py
def case_display():
    print("----------------------------------")
    inverse = len(cases_inplay) * -1
    if len(cases_inplay) <= 7:
        print()
    if 8 < len(cases_inplay) <= 14:
        print()
    if 15 < len(cases_inplay) <= 21:
        print()
    if len(cases_inplay) > 22:
        for case in cases_inplay[-7:-1]:
            print("[" + str(case) + "]", end=' ')
        print()
        for case in cases_inplay[-14:-7]:
            print("[" + str(case) + "]", end=' ')
        print()
        for case in cases_inplay[-21:-14]:
            print("[" + str(case) + "]", end=' ')
        print()
        for case in cases_inplay[inverse:-21]:
            print("[" + str(case) + "]", end=' ')
        print()
    print("----------------------------------")
```

Note that the print() commands within the other if statements are just placeholders. It was my way to calculating rows and stuff.

So this works fine. I know it's not the most efficient way of doing things, but I'm glad that I managed to get this far to be honest! The output that I get from this is:

```
----------------------------------
[20] [21] [22] [23] [24] [25] 
[13] [14] [15] [16] [17] [18] [19] 
[6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] 
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] 
----------------------------------
```

In an ideal world, I would be able to use some sort of table that would align all the "cases" and it would look better. However, the issue with this method is that it isn't showing case 26. I'm understanding that the range is not inclusive at the end [-7,-1]. However, I don't know how to set it to inclusive. If I set it to 0 then that doesn't exactly work.

Looking forward to learning some actual solutions to this problem!

Comment: Use `None` instead of -1.

Comment: @MarkRansom Nah just leave it out.

Comment: @KellyBundy yep, that worked. Thanks. Didn't think I could just leave it at [-7:], figured I needed a number or at least something there. Cheers!

Comment: You need to show us the code for `cases_inplay`. Anyway, all the negative slicing is going to be confusing. You know you can just do `reversed(cases_inplay)` then index it normally? Better yet, why don't you just define `cases_inplay` to be `list(range(26,0,-1)` in the first place?

Comment: @smci, I agree fully. The negative slicing made it a bit confusing but I powered through it since this was never going to scaled up in any way and those numbers don't have to be amended. The code for cases_inplay is just a list that gets items removed from it when they've been selected. I did not know I could use the reversed() function. Thank you :)

Comment: Better still, declare the list `cases_inplay` 26..1 so it's reversed in the first place. Now you just index it normally.

Comment: Careful about optimizing the way you organize your data for what will make the display code simplest.  If it makes life easier overall it's fine, but don't store your data backwards for the sake of making it easier to print if it means your actual game logic is going to have to do everything backwards to compensate for it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the end of the range in order to have it go to the end of the list.  I'd suggest using a loop rather than hardcoding the individual ranges, though, especially if `cases_inplay` is going to shrink over time (e.g. once there are only a few cases you don't need to be printing out `cases_inplay[-21:-14]`).

```
def case_display(cases):
    """Print all cases in rows of 7 in descending order of index, 
    but with the cases in ascending order within each row."""
    print("-" * 34)
    for row in range(len(cases) - 7, -1, -7):
        print(" ".join(f"[{case:02}]" for case in cases[row:row+7]))
    remainder = len(cases) % 7
    if remainder:
        print(" ".join(f"[{case:02}]" for case in cases[:remainder]))
    print("-" * 34)

cases_inplay = list(range(1, 27))
case_display(cases_inplay)
```

prints:

```
----------------------------------
[20] [21] [22] [23] [24] [25] [26]
[13] [14] [15] [16] [17] [18] [19]
[06] [07] [08] [09] [10] [11] [12]
[01] [02] [03] [04] [05]
----------------------------------
```